# Which preposition matched to this context?

Tags: предлоги

Which preposition is correct to put in the following sentence if I want to ask a person to admit on a mistake that he did.

> Ти должен допускат **про /На /за** ето.

Comment: Your sentence does not make sense in Russian. "You should admit your mistake" is *ты должен признать свою ошибку*, without any prepositions.

Answer (score 2):

Ты должен признать свою ошибку (это)

Тебе следует признать свою ошибку

Ты не должен допускать ошибок - you shouldn't make mistakes

я допускаю, что ты не заметил эту ошибку - I admit that you didn't notice this mistake